# Restriction of symplectic form on submanifold

Tags: symplectic-geometry

Consider a symplectic manifold $(M,\omega)$, for a 2 dimensional submanifold $N \subset M$, do we always have $\omega|_{N}$ gives a volume form on $N$?If not, is there any condition we can put on $N$ to make this happen?

Answer (score 4):

Consider $M = T^4$ with the symplectic form $\omega = dx^1\wedge dx^2 + dx^3\wedge dx^4$ and $N = T^2$ embedded in $M$ via the map $i : N \to M$ given by $i(y^1, y^2) = (y^1, 1, y^2, 1)$. Then $\omega|_N = i^*\omega = 0$ which is not a symplectic form on $N$.

A situation where $\omega|_N$ is necessarily a symplectic form is the following: $M$ is a Kähler manifold and $N$ is a complex submanifold (and hence Kähler).